# zsh run command if process is running

Tags: bash, zsh

I want to get some info from `cmus-remote` if `cmus` is running

```
#!/bin/zsh

pgrep cmus>& /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  title=$(cmus-remote -Q | grep tag | grep title | sed 's/tag title //')
  artist=$(cmus-remote -Q | grep tag | grep " artist " | sed 's/tag artist //')
  album=$(cmus-remote -Q | grep tag | grep " album " | sed 's/tag album //')
  track=$(cmus-remote -Q | grep tag | grep tracknumber | sed 's/tag tracknumber //')
  echo $track $title - $artist - $album
else
  echo ""
fi
```

the output for a running cmus is correct, when cmus isn't running I get

```
cmus-remote: cmus is not running
cmus-remote: cmus is not running
cmus-remote: cmus is not running
cmus-remote: cmus is not running
-
```

I have a workaround by appending `>& /dev/null` on each corresponding line but that's not what I want, I would like the code not to be executed at all. And I don't the output from the else case.

Comment: check the solution below. Tested on my system!

Comment: What does the output of `cmus-remote` look like? There is almost certainly a better way to parse this than calling `cmus-remote` and `grep` and `sed` so many times.

Comment: you're right, i did grep 'tag title' etc instead of piping into another grep now. output looks like `tag title Space colonists` each in a new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem that you seem to be having is that your pgrep is returning a hit while you're not expecting it to.

```
pgrep cmus>& /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  //statements here are not evaluated if pgrep\'s exit status is not equal to 0
```

Your pgrep exit code = zero. but it is probably not an exact match (cmus) that was found.
Try narrowing your search with pgrep (i.e. by the usage of the u or x flag)

**tip:** run your bash script with -X to see what the exit code actually was and compare them to the documented exit codes on https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep

Comment: pgrep did return a hit that i wasn't expecting. The problem was me naming my shell script cmus instead of cmus.sh or something else. Renaming and using `pgrep -x 'cmus'` solved the problem

Comment: I didn't exactly get what you mean by running the script with -X to see the exit code? What am i supposed to type into the shell? Btw great **tip**

Comment: There are multiple ways to achieve this.one example is: bash -x cmus.sh in your terminal

Answer (score 0):

```
pgrep cmus>& /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  title=$(cmus-remote -Q | grep tag | grep title | sed 's/tag title //') > /dev/null 2>&1
  artist=$(cmus-remote -Q | grep tag | grep " artist " | sed 's/tag artist //') > /dev/null 2>&1
  album=$(cmus-remote -Q | grep tag | grep " album " | sed 's/tag album //') > /dev/null 2>&1
  track=$(cmus-remote -Q | grep tag | grep tracknumber | sed 's/tag tracknumber //') >/ dev/null 2>&1
  echo $track $title - $artist - $album
else
  echo ""
fi
```

Adding `> /dev/null 2>&1`

2 refers to the second file descriptor of the process, i.e. `stderr`.

`>` means redirection.

`&1` means the target of the redirection should be the same location as the first file descriptor, i.e. `stdout`.

So this command first redirects stdout to `/dev/null` and then redirects stderr there as well. This effectively silences all output (regular or error).

In your case `cmus-remote: cmus is not running` is an `stderr` so the redirection that you should use should be able to redirect both `STDOUT` and `STDERR`

Comment: Thanks but i already knew about redirecting, i did mention the workaround. Is it even possible to redirect the "output" of `/dev/null`. And where is the difference between `> /dev/null` and `>& /dev/null`

Comment: isn't **Solution 2** worse than using `pgrep`?

Comment: @rev I am not aware about `>&` but `&>filename` redirects both `stdout` and `stderr` to file `"filename"`. `&>filename` is same as `>filename 2>&1` . Wanted to give you a clarity on this that is why abbreviated the redirection syntax. In case of `>/dev/null` only `STDOUT` is redirected (File discriptor 1 which is default by bash)

Comment: Also if you are talking about the second solution, there are yet more utilities than `pgrep` and `ps` which could confirm us about the running process. The idea was to convey you about the approach you can go with. If `pgrep` is comfortable for you, it all good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

The best authority on whether `cmus` is running and whether `cmus-remote` can retrieve any information is `cmus-remote`. As such you could just replace `pgrep cmus` with `cmus-remote` as this will exit with return code 1, if `cmus`:

```sh
cmus-remote >& /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   # stuff
fi
```

---

Alternatively you could forego checking beforehand and reduce the amount of external commands called. Just try to parse the output `cmus-remote -Q` and ignore output on `stderr`:

```sh
#!/bin/zsh

cmus-remote -Q 2> /dev/null | awk '
BEGIN {
  tags["album"] = "";
  tags["artist"] = "";
  tags["title"] = "";
  tags["tracknumber"] = ""
}

$1 == "tag" && $2 in tags { 
  tag=$2;
  $1=$2="";
  sub(/  /,"");
  tags[tag] = $0
}

END {
  if (tag)
    printf "%s %s - %s - %s\n", tags["tracknumber"], tags["title"], tags["artist"], tags["album"];
  else
    print ""
}'
```

This calls `cmus-remote` just once and pipes `stdout` to `awk` (also called just once). If `cmus` is not running the error message will be passed to `/dev/null`. `awk` then parses the output of `cmus-remote -Q` and creates the desired output. If `cmus` is not running or if there were no tags, it will print an empty string.

Comment: Works like a charm, wow. That's some heavy use of awk which i have not looked into up till now, which i'm definitely going to do.